# What are the bonuses for supporting civilians on the Citadel in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

After the Priority Palaven mission, I returned to the Citadel to soak up bonus missions and assets.

Trouble is, I have no idea what I need to do regarding the many "Civilian Arguments".  An example would be a situation where a family man is trying to get his docked shuttle permission to deliver refugees, and the Citadel Dock worker says there isn't any room.  Siding with the Citadel worker gives you a bonus to war assets. (Likely due to a freed dock or freed resources).

In many situations, the choice is not easy.  Could anyone provide a list or guide concerning these micro-missions that describe where they are and possible outcomes in an easy to read format?

Comment: For the most part most "support X" arguments just net you +2 rep, but there are some that give War Assets so a little list would be nice.

Comment: The real point of an RPG is to assume the role of the character. What would you do in these situations? It makes the game more fun if you don't look up a guide on what the best outcome is, but instead get given the outcome of a decision you would have made in the same situation.

With that said, this is still a good question.

Comment: The point of the RPG is not lost on me. I'll make the big decisions and level my characters how I chose.  But being that this is a story written by man, I'm not going to pretend that I won't be extremely upset when my efforts are sabotaged by some game designer who ties in petty civilian arguments to my ability to save the universe.

Comment: @tiddy must not...give...spoilers

Comment: @BenBrocka I am becoming increasingly aware that my original motives in asking this question are largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is pretty complete, let me know if you find more and I'll add them in.  I've linked in videos where possible to see where to pick up the conversations, not all videos show the update to the asset however since another conversation might later trigger the actual award.  Much of this information is from the ME Wiki.

**+10**

> After the events of Priority:Citadel 2 the council creates the Citadel Defense Force.  The war asset won't appear until this event.

## At the spectre Terminal

**+8** Authorize [Partner Benefits](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n08VDZDl2Es#t=9m07s) for morale (Normandy Docking Bay after Priority:Mars)

**+7** Authorize Baily to remove the con artist (Picked up near Purgatory Bar)

**+7** Release medical supplies to Huerta Hospital from customs

**+7** Spectre authorization for C-Sec to tap into surveillance on citizens

**+7** Support Worried Merchant at Aeghor Munitions and authorize Militia

**+5** Authorize access and housing for Grissom instructors/students (after Grissom mission)

**-4** If Asari Huntress Weapon Permit is Authorized

## In the docking bay

#### [Refugees](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZNsc2ObCNI#t=1m13s)

**-2** Support the refugee by allowing them to stay

**+7** Support the dock officer, freeing up resources

## In the commons

**-4** If you choose to have C-Sec ignore the sales of illegal weapons to civilians

**+5** Reassure Volus merchants that keeping money in the bank helps the war effort

#### [Reluctant and Gung-Ho Citizens](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVyioKjeHoo#t=38s)

**+5** Support the reluctant citizen, adding to medical support

#### [The book of Plenix](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVyioKjeHoo#t=2m05s)

**+40** News of the book's recovery inspires many Volus citizens to generosity

#### Warning people on the Citadel to prepare for the war

**0**

#### Apollo Cafe

**-2** Support C-Sec officer

**+5** Support Cafe Owner

## Other, eg scanning missions

**+8** Complete Citadel: Target Jamming Technology, see Rannoch: Admiral Koris

**+8** Complete Citadel: Cerberus Automated Turret Schematics, see Tuchanka: Turian Platoon

**+8** Complete Citadel: Biotic Amp Interfaces, see Grissom Academy: Emergency Evacuation

**+40** If Dekuuna: Code of the Ancients is completed

**+40** Find the Rings of Alune by scanning Nevos in the Teyolia system of the Silean Nebula

There is a [conversation between 2 businessmen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVyioKjeHoo#t=6m08s) that updates the Fifth Fleet war asset as well.

Comment: Well you need to be careful. There is a group of successful civilians who want to 'grab a gun' and go fight for the alliance.  Siding with the woman who is reluctant BOOSTS war assets because the untrained soldiers are not bringing down the Alliance, as well as assisting the populace with their day jobs(doctors, teachers, engineers).

Answer (score 1):

The "support" conversations that affect War Assets can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmsYTS1wvgPwdG5iX3FWX2M2UW9Pd1dBSC1hU005V3c#gid=5), on the Modifier sheet, between +10 and -10 value.