# Spectre intel terminal authorizations from ambient conversations

Tags: mass-effect-3

There are several conversations between NPCs on the Citadel that result in an authorization on the Spectre intel terminal. Some examples are the Asari commando and the nurse in the Hospital, Private Talavi and the sergeant in Normandy's Dock, and the C-Sec officers outside Purgatory.

I would like a complete list of all such conversations, where/when they take place, and the result of activating the authorization.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57337/what-are-the-bonuses-for-supporting-civilians-on-the-citadel-in-mass-effect-3

Comment: That does answer the question! Didn't think to search "civilian support" since all these conversations seem to be military/c-sec related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 total:

Partner Benefits
Departing Soldier / Wife
Normandy Dock: Bay D24 Viewing Deck
Unlocked after Priority: Mars
Citadel Defense Force +8

Weapon Authorization
PTSD Soldier / Psych Consultant
Herta Memorial Hospital Patient Lounge
Unlocked after Priority: Mars
Citadel Defense Force -4

Con Artist Deportation
Citadel Guards
Purgatory VIP Entrance
Unlocked after Priority: Palaven
Alliance 3rd Fleet +7

Transfer Request
Private Talavi / Sergeant
Normandy Dock: Bay D24 Passenger Lounge
Unlocked after Priority: The Citadel (Cerberus Attack)
Alliance 3rd Fleet -4

Comment: There's definitely more than this. I'm not able to pull up ME3 to get a list at the moment though sadly.

Comment: The only other multi-part conversation I can think of is the Wife/Mistress one in the Presidium Commons, which I don't think leads to a Spectre Intel terminal authorization. However, un-accepted until more confirmation.